# Updating CSS of Controls in different files via CodeBehind

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, ajax

I have this AJAX button that I want to update some CSS. The problem is that the controls I want it to update are in a different file and can't be moved out of that file.

This is the panel whose CSS I want to update, which is located in the Site.master file:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager" runat="server" />
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="Panel2" runat="server" updatemode="Always">
      <ContentTemplate>
          <div id="updateThis" runat="server"><p>Test text</p></div>
      </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

This is the button, located in the Items.ascx file:

```
<asp:UpdateProgress runat="server" ID="PageUpdateProgress">
     <ProgressTemplate>
         <img class="ajax-loader" src="/Images/ajax-loader.gif" alt="Loading..." />
      </ProgressTemplate>
</asp:UpdateProgress>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="Panel3" runat="server" updatemode="Conditional">
     <Triggers>
         <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger controlid="UpdateButton" eventname="Click" />
     </Triggers>
     <ContentTemplate>

          <asp:Button runat="server" OnClick="UpdateButton"
          OnClientClick="hideButton()" Text="Update" 
          class="update" ID="UpdateButton" name="UpdateButton" 
          type="submit"  ></asp:Button>

     </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

This is the Items.ascx.cs method that is UpdateButton

```
protected void UpdateButton(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    var masterPage = this.Page.Master;
    var updatePanel = masterPage.FindControl("Panel2");

    var div = (HtmlGenericControl)updatePanel.Controls[0].FindControl("updateThis");
    div.Style.Add("color", "#ff0000");  
}
```

When I click the button it doesn't end up working correctly. As of right now, with the AJAX UpdateProgress template, it shows the loading GIF and then the GIF disappears and the text never changes color.

EDIT

Hopefully this will give a better idea of where things might be going wrong:

**THIS WORKS**

```
 protected void UpdateButton(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    var masterPage = this.Page.Master;
    var updatePanel = masterPage.FindControl("Panel2");

    var div = (HtmlGenericControl)updatePanel.FindControl("updateThis");
    div.Style.Add("color", "#ff0000");  

    UpdateButton.Text = "Done!";
}
```

I had #updateThis in the FindControl() method. Don't be like me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add the `runat="server"` attribute to the div control, to make it visible in code-behind:

```
<div id="updateThis" runat="server"><p>Test text</p></div>
```

You can also remove `Controls[0]` in the event handler (but it works if you keep it, according to my tests):

```
protected void UpdateButton(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    var masterPage = this.Page.Master;
    var updatePanel = masterPage.FindControl("Panel2");

    var div = (HtmlGenericControl)updatePanel.FindControl("updateThis");
    div.Style.Add("color", "#ff0000");  
}
```

Comment: Hmmm this doesn't seem to be working for me. You said that removing the Controls[0] from the event handler worked in your test? I wonder why mine might be messing up?

Comment: Just curious: does your original code crash? It should, since `updateThis` cannot be found without the `runat="server"` attribute. As for `Controls[0]`, does it work if you keep it? It works for me with it or without it.

Comment: My page doesn't crash upon clicking the button. The AJAX loader GIF shows up for a brief moment then disappears as if it were working but the Style.Add(); line doesn't seem to be actually working. I commented out the Style.Add(); line and added in UpdateButton.Text = "Done!"; and it changes the text of the button once the AJAX loader GIF disappears. I'm going to update the original post with more info.

Comment: Also, sorry for the peer review. Meant to put it in the original post and accidentally clicked your post haha.

Comment: No problem. Did you add the `runat="server"` attribute to the div in your markup?

Comment: Yeah I added that to the div. Still doesn't seem to want to work

Comment: It works. In the Code Behind, I accidentally had 

var div = (HtmlGenericControl)updatePanel.FindControl("#updateThis");

Removing the # made it work.